# Remove Array Elements Without Array_Unique

Tags: php

Trying to remove duplicate array elements without using array_unique. I am trying to use the array_flip method but that doesn't seem to be working for me. The Code that I have so far is:

```
$arr = array(
   'a' => "one",
   'b' => "two",
   'c' => "three",
   'd' => "two",
   'e' => "four",
   'f' => "five",
   'g' => "three",
   'h' => "two"
);

function removeDuplicates($arr) {


$arr = array_flip($arr);
$arr = array_flip($arr);

}
print_r(removeDuplicates($arr));
```

The output that I am trying to get ultimately is:

```
  [a] => one
    [e] => four
    [f] => five
```

This is just purely for educational purposes as I am trying to find different ways to do it. Any help is great appreciated.

Comment: What happened to "two", and "three"?  Do you want to remove duplicate elements, or elements that have duplicates?

Comment: Your `removeDuplicates` needs a `return $arr;`.

Comment: **php manual**
"array_flip() returns an array in flip order, i.e. keys from trans become values and values from trans become keys."
from
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Comment: @EfthimisCharitonidis: yes, and?

Comment: @Rocket He wants to remove the duplicate values? not exchange the pointers with the value or vice versa

Comment: @EfthimisCharitonidis: Arrays can't have duplicate keys, so `array_flip`ing twice will leave you with unique elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution would be:

```
$counts = array_count_values($arr);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($counts[$value] > 1) {
                unset($arr[$key]);
        }
}
```

Also, array_unique makes sure there are no duplicate values, while you want the array without the values which had duplicates. That is quite different, I guess removing mention of the array_unique function will make the question less confusing.

Answer (score 2):

array_flip will ensure that you don't have any duplicates, but it won't give you the unique values.

The output you are looking for

```
[a] => one
[e] => four
[f] => five
```

is unique values. The array you are probably getting is

```
[a] => one
[b] => two
[c] => three
[e] => four
[f] => five
```

For your output you would need to do something like

```
function array_real_unique($arr, $strict = FALSE) {
    $unique = array();
    $dupes = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (($index = array_search($value, $dupes, $strict)) === FALSE)
            $unique[$key] = $value;
        else
            unset($unique[$index]);
        $dupes[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $unique;
}
```

Comment: +1, good solution.  Though `$dupes` isn't really needed.  You can check if `$index === $key` instead, as `array_search` returns the 1st match.  http://codepad.org/P7erfwYD

Answer (score 1):

If you added `return $arr;` to your code, it'd act the same as `array_unique`.  Well, almost.  `array_unique` would keep the 1st instance of an element, and yours would keep the last.

Your example shows you want to remove elements that have duplicates *not* duplicate elements.  For that, you'd need to get a list of duplicate entries, then remove those values.

**UPDATE:**
Check out [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter), this should work for your situation.

```
// This only works in PHP 5.3+
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($a) use($arr){
    // remove the element if it exists more than once
    return count(array_keys($arr, $a)) === 1; // Get the keys for a value
});
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/l8JkSh